# How to display data from socket io to html page list

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

So, my program gets data from udp server and i just want to display it in list in HTML page 1 by 1 when it updates.
In console it works, but how to do it on page?

I got this code

**index.js**

```
var dgram = require('dgram'),
    server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');  //this server gets data from udp packet

var msg;

server.on('message', function (message, rinfo) {
  msg = message.toString('ascii');   //udp packet data to string 
  console.log(msg);
});

server.on('listening', function () {
  var address = server.address();
  console.log('UDP Server listening ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});
server.bind(8007); 

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var tm = setInterval(function() {
          socket.emit('datafromserver', {'datafromserver': msg});
  }, 500);
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      clearInterval(tm);
  });
});


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and html page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Scoreboard</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
      <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.162:3000/');  
            socket.on('#dataonscreen', function(data) {
            $('#dataonscreen').html(data.datafromserver);
            console.log(data.datafromserver);
            });
      </script>
    <ul id="dataonscreen"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't understand why this isn't working and how to fix it.
Please help!

Comment: Have you imported jquery? Otherwise try with normal javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your socket.io server emits `datafromserver` while your code listens for `#dataonscreen`

Change either so that they are the same value and your code should work. I'm not sure how you have console output since the event is not being listened for

Comment: Ok so which did you change? What is the client side console output

Comment: UDP Server listening 0.0.0.0:8007
listening on *:3000
colduzi killed Caddy with ak47
o=b.o= JoXyo=b.o=  killed acezy- with ak47
KING CRIMSON killed colduzi with m4a1_silencer (headshot)
P4P5P;P1P8P: killed NEXten with hegrenade
b* KSMm killed P4P5P;P1P8P: with aug

Comment: i changed this parts ` socket.on('#datafromserver', function(data) {
            $('#datafromserver').html(data.datafromserver);
            console.log(data.datafromserver);
            });
      </script>

    <ul id="datafromserver"></ul> `

Comment: You should remove the `#` before `datafromserver` in `socket.on`.

Comment: now it works! thanks but how to do message output 1 by 1 like list

Comment: if `data.datafromserver` is an array, you could use ```data.datafromserver.map(a=>`<li>${a}</li>`)``` to turn each element into a list item

Comment: and what can i do if it isn't array? or how to declare it as array?

Comment: Just `$("#datafromserver").html("<li>"+data.datafromserver+"</li>")`

Comment: it isn't work like you said.
[on my server](http://188.234.82.137) you can see it

Comment: If you want to append data to the ul, use  `$("#datafromserver").html($("#datafromserver").html()+"<li>"+data.datafromserver+"</li>")`